# Finding UserControl in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

Good afternoon!

The form has a FlowLayoutPanel with a list of users (created in UserControl)
A UserControl is added to the FlowLayoutPanel with data taken from the json file.

How can I search for the UserName tag through a text field by hiding the elements.
For example, I enter "Ben", all elements in the FlowLayoutPanel that do not match the request are hidden. Only those with "Ben" in the UserName remain

UserControl Code:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Partial Public Class CustomListItem
    Inherits UserControl

    Private _UserName As String
    Private _ID As Integer
    Private _Login As String
    Private _Title As String
    Private _Dep As String
    Private _Mail As String
    Private _Phone As String
    Private _Picture As Image

    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property UserName() As String
        Get
            Return _UserName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _UserName = value
            Lbl_UserName.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _ID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _ID = value
            Lbl_ID.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Login() As String
        Get
            Return _Login
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Login = value
            Lbl_Login.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return _Title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Title = value
            Lbl_Title.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Dep() As String
        Get
            Return _Dep
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Dep = value
            Lbl_Dep.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Phone() As String
        Get
            Return _Phone
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Phone = value
            Lbl_Phone.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property


    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Mail() As String
        Get
            Return _Mail
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Mail = value
            Lbl_Mail.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Custom Props")>
    Public Property Picture() As Image
        Get
            Return _Picture
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Image)
            _Picture = value
            pic_img.Image = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub CustomListItem_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
        BackColor = Color.White
    End Sub

    Private Sub CustomListItem_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
        BackColor = Color.Silver
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Form code:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1
    Public listUser As List(Of UserList)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        listUser = New List(Of UserList)()
        Dim json = File.ReadAllText("D:\Users.json")

        listUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of UserList))(json)
        Dim listItems = New CustomListItem(29) {}
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
      
        For Each UserList In listUser.Take(30)
            listItems(i) = New CustomListItem With {
                .ID = UserList.Id,
                .UserName = UserList.UserName,
                .Login = UserList.Login,
                .Title = UserList.Title,
                .Dep = UserList.Dep,
                .Mail = UserList.Mail,
                .Phone = UserList.Phone,
                .Picture = My.Resources.User128
            }

            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listItems(i))
            i += 1
        Next UserList

    End Sub
End Class
Public Class UserList
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    Public Property UserName() As String
    Public Property Login() As String
    Public Property Title() As String
    Public Property Dep() As String
    Public Property Mail() As String
    Public Property Phone() As String
End Class
```

[image]

Another request to clarify the moment what these lines mean (and specifically the numbers in them)

```vb
 Dim listItems = New CustomListItem(29) {}
...
 For Each UserList In listUser.Take(30)
```

As I understand, this is the number of UserControls created in the FlowLayoutPanel. But my number of entries in the json file may be different, not known to me. And it will not be possible to count each time the entries in the json file. Tell me, how can I get away from the specific number of UserControls created in the FlowLayoutPanel?

Thank you in advance for your answers and comments. Have a good day!

And of course the JSON file itself:

```
[
{
"id":"1",
"UserName":"Fred Smith",
"Login":"f.smith",
"Title":"engineer",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"f.smith@domain.com",
"Phone":"111",
},
{
"id":"2",
"UserName":"Ben Taylor",
"Login":"b.taylor",
"Title":"programmer",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"b.taylor@domain.com",
"Phone":"100",
},
{
"id":"3",
"UserName":"Steve Harris",
"Login":"s.harris",
"Title":"System Administrator",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"s.harris@domain.com",
"Phone":"263",
},
{
"id":"4",
"UserName":"Tom Walker",
"Login":"t.walker",
"Title":"engineer",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"t.walker@domain.com",
"Phone":"263",
},
{
"id":"5",
"UserName":"Tom Davis",
"Login":"t.davis",
"Title":"engineer",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"t.davis@domain.com",
"Phone":"200",
},
{
"id":"6",
"UserName":"Ben Walker",
"Login":"b.walker",
"Title":"System Administrator",
"Dep":"IT infrastcomcture",
"Mail":"b.walker@domain.com",
"Phone":"167",
},
]
```

Comment: So there are a few suggestions.  Depending on how "live" you want the filtering to be, you could clear the FLP, apply your filter to listUser then rebuild the FLP/User controls.  Might be a bit chunky redrawing it all.  Another option might be to Bind a boolean to the Visible property of the UserControl.  As for the 2nd question, looks to me your assumption is right, it's limiting the collection to 30 records.  If that's right or wrong really only you can say, but would agree seems a little off to me as well

Comment: *"Another request..."*. No. each question on SO must be specific. You don't ask two different things in one question. If you have a different question to ask then post it separately, including all and only the information relevant to that question.

Comment: FYI, the operation you're trying to perform is not called "finding" but "filtering".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that every control in your `FlowLayoutPanel` is the same type:

```vb
For Each cli As CustomListItem In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
    cli.Visible = (cli.UserName = filterValue)
Next
```

Each user control will be visible if and only if its `UserName` property is equal to the specified value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Everything works, only when you click on the button. Did it like this:
`For Each cli As CustomListItem In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
            cli.Visible = (cli.UserName.Contains("Ben"))` But how to make it so that the filtering would be in the event of the TextBox1_TextChanged text field when entering values

Comment: @Lider13, you're really asking me how to move code from one event handler to another?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I made a mistake) first I wrote, then I thought. Thank you very much for your help!